# Create a object initialization loop using Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a set of constant values that are available as a list. Using these values I have to create a key value pair object and this object has to be added to a list. I would like to achieve this using Stream API in JAVA 8. Below is the sample implementation using a for loop

```
for (int i=0; i<length; i+=2){    
    list.add(new sampleObject(constant[i],constant[i+1]);
}
```

Can this be implemented using Stream reduction operations?

Comment: If you want to start with Arrays.stream(constant), there’s no nice way to pair off the elements of a stream like that. A for loop is the clearest solution imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain `IntStream.iterate()` that produces a infinite `IntStream` with `IntStream.limit()` to make it finite :

```
List<sampleObject> list = 
    IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2)
              .limit(Math.ceil(length / 2D))
              .mapToObj(i -> new sampleObject(constant[i], constant[i+1]))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: There should be division by 2 somewhere in that limit

Answer (score 3):

Of course it can!

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < length, i -> i + 2)
         .mapToObj(i -> new sampleObject(constant[i], constant[i+1]))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm not sure off the top of my head, but `constant` may have to be `final` or effectively `final` for this to compile.

**Note**: I just realized, this overloaded `iterate` method was added in Java 9.  Please see [davidxxx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49456511/7294647) for a Java 8 solution!

Comment: constant will be an array which will have values that may be defined in the class at a later point but will not change once defined. Would that be enough?

Comment: @JavaiMaster As long as `constant` isn't re-assigned, then you're fine.  I'd stick with the for-loop if I were you though; it's a lot more intuitive.

Comment: @Jacob G. The second parameter of iterate() is `IntUnaryOperator`. I don't understand the meaning of your lambda. Could you explain ?

Comment: @davidxxx Of course!  I used the [overloaded `iterate` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) that accepts three parameters (which I just realized was added in Java 9).  Because this question is tagged `java-8`, I reckon your answer should be accepted.

Comment: @Jacob All right ! Excellent overload in Java 9 that misses in Java 8 : the `Math.ceil()` to handle odd length is ugly and error prone.